# What resources should a PhD student expect their advisor to have?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, advisor, supervision

I am contemplating changing PhD advisors and wanted opinions as to whether I am being too critical and if there is any basis to my concerns.

I am a little over a year into the PhD program and am with an advisor who is known within the department for having diverse research interest, a jack of many trades. In my opinion this has significantly limited my advisor's ability to advise the work of the PhD students in the lab beyond an introductory level. Nor has this provided my advisor with any significant level of resources such as ideas, publications, or people in any one area of research.

In the time I have been in the lab I have published three first author papers. These were all ideas I originated with no assistance from my advisor; I used none of the resources in the lab; I ran the experiments and wrote the manuscripts; I found the journals to publish the papers in; and I responded to and submitted all the edits. In all cases there was no publishing fee because my advisor has no funding.

I sometimes feel like the only duty my advisor exists for is simply to sign on the dotted line in cases where I need somebody to testify I have met the program's degree requirements as I progress though the program. I do not want, or expect, an advisor to hold my hand through my PhD. Nor do I expect my advisor to know everything about what I am doing. What would I be contributing to science if someone else already knew everything about what I was researching? I did however assume an advisor would be someone who could judge and debate the intellectual scope and merit of the research their advisees are performing beyond a introductory level. I also assumed an advisor would have resources I could use to propel my research forward.

I fear that my current trajectory could easily lead me towards earning a PhD with mediocre research and publications unless I exercise extreme vigilance. I feel like my advisor is ill equipped to provide ideas, publications, people, and/or other resources to contribute towards strengthening my research. I fear this could significantly hurt my ability to be competitive for positions after my PhD.

Are my fears warranted? Am I being too critical of my advisor? Are my expectations unrealistic about the resources an advisor should be able to provide? How common is this among advisors and I would be just as likely to run into these same issues if switched to a new advisor?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this just a rant? One year in and three first author papers. It sounds like you are doing fine.

Comment: How can you run an experiment without using resources?

Comment: It sounds like you can be very successful without relying on your advisor. Those of us waiting weeks for feedback or for projects to proceed would be very jealous.

Comment: Your advisor may be saying "this student is doing great without my help; he doesn't need me, and he probably doesn't even want my advice." Talk to him — ask him whether he thinks the direction of your research is worthwhile and will get you a good job, or whether you should change the focus towards something more high-profile (since this seems to be one of your main concerns, and may be something he can advise you on).

Comment: @Buffy I am sorry, I am not trying to rant. I have been able to publish and I am happy for that. However, I have no idea how good the journals I published in are outside of their impact factor. Nor, do I know if anyone in the field I am interested in even cares about these journals. My advisor can't answer either of these questions. My advisor is using the journals' acceptance of my work as validation that my work is even a good idea, because my advisor can't evaluate that either.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- My research is in computer science and I have designed my experiments so I could do them with just my laptop as my resource. I am sorry if I came across as bragging in post, that is not my intent.

Comment: @PeterShor I think ensuring my work is sufficiently high-profile enough to be competitive with other PhD students hits the nail directly on the head! Thank you! I also agree, communication is key and there might be more lines of communication I could try to open with my advisor outside of the ones I have tried. I will admit my confidence in my advisor's ability to critically analyze my work isn't terribly high based on prior conversations though. My advisor has used the acceptance of my work to journals as proof of its validity.

Comment: What about working with your advisor to help you figure out which conferences may be good in your area and how to network with others who can fill the gaps in your current mentorship relationship? It sounds like it is time for you to expand your mentorship relationships, but that doesn’t necessarily mean you need to leave this lab.

Comment: Here are some resources from NCFDD about all the different kinds of mentors people need (I especially like their mentor map) - https://www.facultydiversity.org/rethinkingmentoringcw

Comment: @Dawn Excellent point, thank you! Perhaps simply building out my network of mentors is a better option since no one single mentor can do everything. Now if we can just get past the pandemic so I can start networking more actively in person to meet more mentors, lol!

Comment: Actually, I would say pandemic is an ideal time to attend virtual seminars and then follow up with folks!